# Intellij Analyze data flow in Javascript/Typescript code

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea

Currently, there is a feature in Intellij for Java code where I can analyze data flow for given methods.

Is there anything similar for Javascript/Typescript code?

Comment: There's [madge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge), don't know if that's the sort of thing you're looking for though

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature for JS/TS yet. You can follow this request: [WEB-28992](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28992).